# iBeacon contents always suggest Android tag instead of iOS tag

Tags: discussion

I asked quite a few questions about iBeacons these days. I noticed that Stack Overflow always suggests [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) instead of [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) after I entered the contents. The contents are irrelevant to Android at all, and did not mention anything relate to Android. How come it will suggest [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) ?

I expect Stack Overflow will suggest [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [ibeacon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibeacon) instead.

Comment: I guess this has to do with tags relevancy on SO's existing questions. I have seen many Android questions related to iBeacon. Perhaps it is tagged more on Android question than iOS?

Comment: iBeacon is Apple's technology. For questions about simulating iBeacon feature in Android, it should be tagged with ibeacon-android tag instead, I think.